# How to hide label if field is empty?

Tags: 7, theming

so I have a content-type `X` and some nodes of this type. If I go to the node page, I'd like to not see the label of an empty field. Where in the display options can I change that?

In my case ,the content of the fields are some check-boxes (from a vocabulary). I'm on D7.

Comment: Just use CSS: `label:empty { display: none; }`. It has pretty good browser support

Comment: why render somethign that's not used anyway? als ocss does not work here since it actually generates a link which is weird.

Comment: It was a quick hack. If you were worried about best practice you wouldn't be removing the label, surely? It breaks accessibility guidelines/legislation

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074834/drupal-7-hiding-labels-with-empty-fields-when-viewing-a-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the settings in `/admin/structure/taxonomy/X/display` (label settings)

but it should be done automatically if there is no content

Comment: yeah was a strange misconfiguration